# Inserting ListView in the sweeping tabs

Tags: android, listview, fragment

good evening guys, i am creating a chat application and im inserting a Fragment adapter for putting sweeping tabs for its Main class,but i need my tabs have listview in each one, so i need them to extend both listview and Fragment in order to do so normally, for that reason i need alittle help from experienced guys , if you know any tricks or way i can make it this way, i really appreciate it.
and by the way here is my adapter :

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();

    }

    return null;
}
```

and this part of my mainactivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.menu_all:
        tours = datasource.findAll();
        refreshDisplay();
        break;

    case R.id.menu_cheap:
        tours = datasource.findFiltered("price <= 300", "price ASC");
        refreshDisplay();
        break;

    case R.id.menu_fancy:
        tours = datasource.findFiltered("price >= 1000", "price DESC");
        refreshDisplay();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

thanks

Comment: There is a class known as ListFragment, why don't you extend ListFragment?

Comment: did not know ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend ListFragment instead of Fragment. This will help you build a fragment with lists.

You may check the following documentation [ListFragment official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

So you would need to do something similar to this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListFragment;

public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
   }

   @Override
   public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   // do something with the data
   }
}
```

Comment: yes ,very well, thanks alot :) i assume there is no way putting an activity in tab right?

Comment: yes of course, instead of using the GamesFragment, which extends the Fragment, you can create a new class, called List for example and making it extend ListFragment.